# Performance issues with translate3d transform transition?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

the two css classes are,

```
 .slideOut {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}

.slideIn {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

I have not seen any flickering in chrome browser and not even in iphone but when I run the application on some android devices like Samsung s3, the view flickers when the height of the view exceeds the height of the devices.
What can be done to remove this issue.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "when the height of the view exceeds the height of the devices" - I dont believe this should happen ? elaborate...

Comment: @user2515563 Yes if a scroll bar comes in the screen I see some flickering at the start of the transition.

Comment: i see.. I've been developing for mobile awhile, and ive noticed as ive tested some devices on numerous occasions that they flicker some and have a hard time rendering properly..specifically with transitions.. Maybe try a different device... Im thnking this could be hardware..